# Is there an easy way to evaluate JavaScript within WebStorm?

Tags: javascript, webstorm

Is there a way to easily evaluate arbitrary JavaScript code within WebStorm for testing purposes?

I'm tired of jsFiddle.net. I basically want a [REPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) within WebStorm but where I can also format blocks of code.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well, you can get a `REPL` using webstorm's new Terminal functionality:

[image]

Press enter on "Open Terminal".

Once you're in terminal, just enter `node` and then you get a `REPL`. This assumes that you have `nodejs` installed.

However, if you want a REPL for the web, then I would suggest that you use Google Chrome's or Firefox's REPL.

Comment: Is there a way/shortcut to send the current line from the editor to the terminal?

Comment: Sadly, AFAIK there's no autocomplete in node REPL

Comment: Would be awesome to have a "Node Console" similar to the "Python Console" in PyCharm